# Unknown column 'Extent2.IdentityUser_Id' in 'field list'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I got this error message `Unknown column 'Extent2.IdentityUser_Id' in 'field list'` when I try to customize Application User.

Full error:

> Unknown column `Extent2.IdentityUser_Id' in 'field list'`

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown column 'Extent2.IdentityUser_Id' in 'field list'`
>
> `Line 96: var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);`

I have existed Mysql db with user table. I can not to use other table. I have to keep MyUser table and I add some table follow Asp.Net Identity definitions:

In IdentiyModels.cs :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext(): base("KadContext")
            {
            }
    
            public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
            {
                return new ApplicationDbContext();
            }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("ad_users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("id");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("ad_users").Property(p => p.UserName).HasColumnName("user_name");
                p.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("user_password");
                modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("ad_users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("id");
                modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("ad_users").Property(p => p.UserName).HasColumnName("user_name");
                
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("ad_userroles");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("ad_userlogins");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("ad_userclaims");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("ad_roles");
            }
        }
```

I want to hook into OWIN Self Hosting to create Authencation for login features

In AccountController.cs :

```
//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
  
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
    var identity = await SignInManager.CreateUserIdentityAsync(user);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

I only to use AuthencationManager to manage Authencation after I check user permission from LDAP server. So that I want to hook ASP.NET Identity OWIN on MVC 5 system.

Does anyone see this error? I need a solution to go through it.

---

I found this way I want can not reach . Due to ASP.NET Identity OWIN on MVC 5 System need a sets of tables User, Roles, Claims. If you want to custom them should follow here http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity2.0-Custom-Database/

- I also am trying to hook like an external system (ex google, facebook...) .  I think I must create an temp request from external system with full information after request ASP.Identity  OWIN allow create Authentication User.

Does anyone have full solution for that!?